# Issue with my app after Android 5.0.1 update. "SurfaceView" turns into transparent mode

Tags: java, android

I use SlideMenu in my app. “Menu” in one fragment and “SurfaceView” in another. When opening “Menu”, preview disappears during camera movement and SurfaceView turns into transparent mode.
Using setZOrderOnTop(true) - SurfaceView doesn’t disappear, but overlaps a lot of elements, that should be over it.
Untill Android 5.0.1 update everything was fine.
Can you give me an advice? 
[image]

Comment: show some legit proof to your statements

Comment: I have attached picture

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the hardware acceleration in the manageLayers method of SlidingMenu. This seems to be the only solution since SurfaceViews don't work.

com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu

Edit function manageLayers:

```
//final int layerType = layer ? View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE : View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE;
final int layerType = View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE;
```

Comment: @x802 [upvote and accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) for future readers